# Как построить такую логику вывода постов на страницу?

Tags: wordpress

подскажите как правильно вывести посты (дома) таким образом.

Есть страница, вверху фильтры и кнопка поиска, при нажатии на поиск, без перезагрузки выводятся дома по критериям фильтров.

А постоянно на эту страницу выводятся все микрорайоны (микрорайон это рубрика)

Внутри блока микрорайон есть слайдер с домами этого микрорайона(custom post type)

Подскажите как это сделать, какие именно циклы использовать, и чем по сути является эта страница, архивной страницой домов? Скриншот приложил

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вывод постов (те что вверху), это или основной цикл или `WP_Query`, здесь будет зависеть от того, будет ли это какая-то отдельная страница, со своим темплейтом (иногда это может быть обусловлено разными причинами, по типу что некоторые секции клиент хотел бы редактировать и тп.) или же действительно архив вашего пост тайпа, здесь уже смотрите как Вам будет удобно и будет нужно.

Ниже (там где микрорайоны), я бы использовал `get_terms()` для получения микрорайонов и внутри перебора использовал бы `WP_Query`, я набросал простой пример, чтобы было более понятно (все div и прочие обертки, просто для наглядности):

```
<div class="content">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php // Здесь ваши фильтры ?>
        <?php // Это Ваш цикл или основной или заменяете на WP_Query, зависит от ситуации ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php //... Тут темплейт парт или что вам нужно ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php $terms = get_terms( 'my_taxonomy' ); // Заменяете на вашу кастомную таксономию

        if ( $terms && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) : ?>
            <div class="term-wrapper">
                <h2><?php echo esc_html( $term->name ); ?></h2><?php // Название микрорайона ?>
                <?php foreach( $terms as $term ) : ?>
                    <?php $query = new WP_Query( [
                        'post_type'      => 'your_post_type', // Заменяете на Ваш пост тайп
                        'posts_per_page' => 6, // Указываете нужное Вам количество
                        'tax_query'      => [
                            [
                                'taxonomy' => 'your_tax_name',
                                'field'    => 'id',
                                'terms'    => $term->term_id
                            ]
                        ]
                    ] );

                    if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
                        <div class="slider-wrapper">
                            <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                                <?php //... Тут темплейт парт или что вам нужно ?>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо огромное